# The sum of three natural numbers are $111$, and the three numbers are in geometric progression.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Find all triples of natural numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b$ and $c$ are in geometric progression, and $a+b+c=111$.

Any pointers?

Comment: a+ar+ar^2+...+ar^n-1 = a(1-r^n)/1-r                                                                Let's say we have a gem. seq. where a, b, c are the last 3 terms.To get those: ar^n-3 + ar^n-2 + ar^n-1 = (a(1-r^n)/1-r) - (a(1-r^n-3)/1-r); but this hasn't helped much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

> $$
> 111 = 3 \times 37.
> $$

Note also that

> $$
> a = p, b = p q, c = p q^2.
> $$

Whence
$$
3 \times 37 = p \big( 1 + q + q^2 \big).
$$

## Case $p = 111$

We obtain
$$
3 \times 37 = 111 \big( 1 + q + q^2 \big) \Rightarrow 1 + q + q^2 = 1
\rightarrow q = 0.
$$

Therefore

> $$
> (a,b,c) = (111,0,0).
> $$

But this is no geometric progression.

## Case $p = 37$

We obtain
$$
3 \times 37 = 37 \big( 1 + q + q^2 \big) \Rightarrow 1 + q + q^2 = 3
\Rightarrow q = 1
$$

Therefore

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { (a,b,c) = (37,37,37) }
> $$

## Case $p = 3$

We obtain
$$
3 \times 37 = 3 \big( 1 + q + q^2 \big) \Rightarrow 1 + q + q^2 = 37.
\Rightarrow q = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{145} \notin \mathbb{N}.
$$

Therefore no solutions.

## Case $p = 1$

We obtain
$$
3 \times 37 = \big( 1 + q + q^2 \big) \Rightarrow 1 + q + q^2 = 111.
\Rightarrow q = 10.
$$

Therefore

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { (a,b,c) = (1,10,100) }
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let the numbers in G.P. be $$kr, k, \frac{k}{r}$$
having a common ratio $r$

As per given condition you have $$kr+ k+\frac{k}{r}=111$$

Comment: Do you mean $ak$ instead of $rk$?

Comment: '$a$' is given so  I had to take $k$  for distinction between numbers